# Route to same component

Tags: angular

I have component lets say customer purchase history which shows the info about the purchase a customer has done. I will be showing list of previous purchases done by customer.

When i click on a previous purchase i want to load the same component showing that purchase info means i want to navigate to same component with route with route-reuse enable. I want to show the earlier purchase history when i go back. Can somebody please tell me how can do it.

I have done a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ndcXa1TuWtRCX1ZtGMYq?p=preview) demo here  which holds list of all purchases and purchases done by a customer.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/PurchaseHistory');
```

Is it possible to route to same component with route reuse enabled?

Comment: Why isn't the id in path? like `/PurchaseHistory/:id`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to reload the `PurchaseData` in `CrisisListComponent`. Routing to the same route is redundant then. Please see the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/W1VdlnSd1avqTAh6JPFu).

```
EditPurchase(index:any){
  let Id:any=this.PreviousPurchases[index].PurchaseId;
  this.purSrvc.GetPurchaseHistoryByPurchaseId(Id);
  this.getPurchaseData();
  // this.router.navigateByUrl('/PurchaseHistory');
}
```

Other (I'd recommend this one) approach you could use here (to i.a. properly handle browser's back button) is to add the id to your route:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'PurchaseHistory/:id', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'PurchaseHistoryList', component: HeroListComponent, data: { shouldDetach: true} },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/PurchaseHistoryList', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

update paths in router.navigate() instructions and subscribe to router.params events.

Comment: Thank you... the plunker which you made actually gets the the previous record and updating the UI. I wanted the constructor to fire again.because if i click of browser back i want the previous purchase history i.e it is to be saved using route reuse